# Where does this argument to __before_compile__ get set in Phoenix.Endpoint?

Tags: elixir, metaprogramming, phoenix-framework

The following source code from https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/v1.5/lib/phoenix/endpoint.ex#L602

`defmacro __before_compile__(%{module: module}) do`

looks like a map argument is being passed to **before_compile** . But the [documentation for @before_compile](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.12/Module.html#module-before_compile) says "A hook that will be invoked before the module is compiled. Accepts a module or a {module, function_or_macro_name} tuple. See the "Compile callbacks" section below.".

1. Where is the key value of `module` being determined in the argument `%{module: module}` being passed to `__before_compile__` ?
2. And why is a map being passed in to before_compile in direct contradiction to the docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the [`@before_compile`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.12/Module.html#module-before_compile-1) as a compilation hook, it looks like this (from the docs):

```
defmodule B do
  @before_compile A
end
```

What gets called is the `__before_compile__` macro in the target, which *does* receive one argument, which is a map, e.g.

```
defmodule A do
  defmacro __before_compile__(%{module: module}) do
     # Do pre-compile stuff
  end
end
```

The source code you referenced `defmacro __before_compile__(%{module: module}) do` is using pattern matching to extract the `module` that called it (e.g. module `B` in the example above) because it needs to know the module name to operate on it.